# how to update value of Qsetting while changing value in inputbox with connect statement in QT

Tags: linux, qt

I just want to update the value in Qsettings while changing in Qlineedit using connect statement only means I dont want to make any function for update value in Qsettings.

Comment: You can't do that using a connect statement only (there is no slot in `QSettings` that updates a specific value). you need to have a slot that will get executed when `QLineEdit`'s value changes, and in this slot, you can use `QSettings` normally to update whatever value you want.

Comment: Yes that the same thing i want to do but can you give me somecode for it how to implement it?

Comment: connect(eic_smoothingWindow, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), SLOT(  )); 
How can i pass below things in slot ?
settings->setValue("eic_smoothingAlgorithm",
                       eic_smoothingAlgorithm->currentIndex());

Comment: connect(eic_smoothingWindow, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), SLOT(settings->setValue("eic_smoothingAlgorithm",
                       eic_smoothingAlgorithm->currentIndex()))); 
It is not working @Mike

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve this is probably by using new signal/slot syntax (https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)
with lambda expression as slot. I am not sure what type of widget you are using because *QLineEdit* does not have *valueChanged* signal (there is only *textChanged* signal), so I assume you must be using *QSpinBox*. Below is the example code for both cases (*QLineEdit* and *QSpinBox*)

```
connect(ui->lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [=](const QString& str)
{
   QSettings().setValue("attribute",str);
});

connect(ui->spinBox, static_cast<void (QSpinBox::*)(int)>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged), [=](int val)
{
   QSettings().setValue("numAttribute",val);
});
```